# Why you can't search the word 'most'?

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

I just tried searching for the word `most` and the search instructions came up instead of the results.

Is it some keyword, or am I missing something?

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24575/so-sites-dont-search-for-common-words

Comment: Out of curiosity, what useful results were you hoping to get based on the search "most"?

Answer (score 2):

This particular word works with the new search engine, the stop list has changed as we have changed the underlying search technology.