# Search does not find user post by a single word, only with two words

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

I was trying to find an older answer of mine to this post on SO:

[Purpose of private members in a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374988/purpose-of-private-members-in-a-class)

I more or less remembered that it was about private members, so I ran a search for [`user:265143 private`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A265143+private) - the post was not found.

Then I tried [`user:265143 member`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A265143+member) - again without success.

Finally [`user:265143 private member`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A265143+private+member) turned up what I was looking for.

The list of results contained 11 posts for the first query and 19 for the 2nd, so the result lists are not supposed to be paginated. Also, I copied the search terms as they appeared in the Search box after the search returned, so I guess this is not an issue of a word being turned into a tag, as in [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31908/search-for-so-questions-by-words-in-the-title-is-failing-purpose-trying-to-find), or omitted, as [in here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24575/so-sites-dont-search-for-common-words).

---

This is quite possibly a duplicate, but I just couldn't find any original - please let me know if there is one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works in the new search system, several search related bugs were resolved when we moved away from SQL full text search.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, searching with quotes (as in [`user:265143 "private"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A265143+%22private%22) or [`user:265143 "member"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A265143+%22member%22)), or a plus sign (as in [`user:265154 +private`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A265143+%2bprivate) or  [`user:265154 +member`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A265143+%2bmember)) show your post.