# Search just code

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search, code, source-code

I want to search my questions for a question that uses the C# key word <del>`is`</del> `new`.

When I search `user:me new` I get matches that are not code.  Is there a way to just search code?

Edit: Since it seems that this cannot be done currently, I am switching it to a feature request.  Since `is` will not get past the stop word filter, I am changing the example to use `new`.

Comment: Are you asking for how to search for keywords that happen to be [stop words](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24575/so-sites-dont-search-for-common-words/24578#24578), or how to search for text that is specifically inside of indented code blocks?

Comment: In code blocks.

Comment: @NickCraver does the [status-completed] tag mean you're [not still testing it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122792/search-for-operators#comment326666_122792)? I ask because I've found a bug with it but I'm not sure if I should post it on meta if its "not done"

Comment: @GraceNote Unfortunately `code:"new"` is broken, for example typing *that* into the search bar finds this Q&A and many other posts containing the word "new".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[As lunboks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132613/shouldnt-the-search-term-select-return-items-with-the-phrase-select#comment367146_132613) notes you can search code blocks with the `code:` search term.

e.g. `code:"new"`

So you should be able to use `user:me code:"new"` to find what you're looking for.

It doesn't appear to search bodies or titles, but I couldn't find any documentation for it.