# Search for operators

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to search for punctuation/special characters?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32879/is-it-possible-to-search-for-punctuation-special-characters)

It seems to be impossible to search for !!, << and probably more essential characters and character combinations used in programming.

I tried searching for: `!!`, `"!!"`, `title:!!` and `title:"!!"` but all return no results.

Comment: [`code:"!!"`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=code%3A%22%21%21%22), shhh don't tell anyone, we're still testing this out.

Comment: SymbolHound returns a lot of results for SO too http://symbolhound.com/ I've been using it ... hopefully only up until about now.

Comment: @NickCraver I don't think you know how this works ...

Comment: It appears it [was broken in April 2022](https://stackapps.com/questions/2690/symbolhound-search-stack-overflow-for-special-characters#comment18724_2690).