# Why is the "code:" search option not documented?

Tags: support, status-completed, search

When searching for a post, it is possible to filter the posts by a string that must be present in a block code, such as with [code:"preg_match"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=code:%22preg_match%22&submit=search).  
This search option is not [documented](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching), though.

Does this mean the option could be removed at any moment, or is it an option that is subject to changes?

Comment: [Shhhh!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122792/search-for-operators#comment326666_122792) It *has* been a while though, so I'm not sure if it's still "in-testing" or not.

Comment: Should I have titled the question "Shhhh! Why is the 'code:' […]"? `;)`

Comment: @kiamlaluno That would attract less attention than "Eeeeeek! Why is the 'code:'..."

Comment: [Add Code search syntax to search tips](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146546/add-code-search-syntax-to-search-tips)

Comment: It's not a secret, but it's not polished either...I was interrupted in the middle of implementing it and haven't re-visited it in a while.  You're welcome to use it and we won't remove it.  That being said, I don't feel it's 1.0 quality at this point, so haven't added it to documentation as I expect there are bugs I'll find with more testing locally.  We're doing a *lot* behind the scenes right now, when that settles down I'll re-visit search (we have lots of ideas/code in the pipe there).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has since made in into the [Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching) article on searching:

> To search only within code blocks: `code:"new"` to search code within posts for the word "new".

As far as I can tell, this was added at some point in [May 2020](https://web.archive.org/web/20200508125501/https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching), checking through the Web Archive to see when that line first appeared.