# Has this bug been fixed: "Is it possible to search for punctuation/special characters?"

Tags: support, search

Sorry if this is a duplicate question. I'm working on my searching skills.

What I get from the original post is that this question was asked then tagged as a possible bug in 2009, and then tagged with status-completed in early 2013. Also from the discussion it seems that searching for special characters is no longer possible. This was what I experienced when I tried to search for `:+` and `":+"` on stackoverflow.

Am I reading this correctly? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Search for `code:":+"`

> [Nick Craver](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/135201/nick-craver) commented [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122792/search-for-operators#comment326666_122792) that this feature is currently in testing as a [Advanced Super Ninja Search Option](https://stackoverflow.com/search), `code`. So to search for `!!` in code, you run the query [`code:"!!"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=code%3A%22%21%21%22&submit=search)

Source https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123700/267099

Comment: Nice, but special chars are not always in the code.

Comment: Thanks @DavidPostill, this helps.

Comment: I agree with @nicael. It would be good to be able to search the entire post or even the title for special characters.