# Shouldn't the search term "SELECT!" return items with the phrase SELECT?

Tags: feature-request, search, feedback

I am not yelling. I am specifically looking for the term SELECT!, that is `SELECT<exclamation-point>`. When I do a search and put "SELECT!" in the search box, I would expect to see results that include that EXACT phrase. Even Google fails with 'site:stackoverflow.com "SELECT!"'. Is this even possible with current SO search techniques?

Comment: So which is it? I can't be both a bug and a feature-request. Pick one.

Comment: Are you wanting to search in code, or in regular post text?

Comment: Actually, you're wrong. It could be a bug, or it could be a feature request. If the issue is that search is not working properly, then it is a bug. If search is working by design, then it is a feature request. But I won't get in a tag edit war with you.

Comment: For the second comment, either really. Is there a way to differentiate the search?

Comment: [How do comment @replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

Comment: The search worked perfectly... you asked for SELECT NOT, which is what you got. Just sayin'.

Comment: Google symbolhound, it may be useful...

Comment: FWIW, you can search code blocks by using [`code:"SELECT!"`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=code%3A%22SELECT!%22), but that doesn't work with post bodies and titles.

Comment: @lunboks wow neat feature! Something new every day... :/

Comment: @Tim Symbolhound rules. Thanks.