# What's wrong with my search terms?

Tags: support, search

I was trying to look for an answer of mine earlier and did a search like this:

```
user:me SQLite RunInTransaction
```

The above found nothing. So I changed it to

```
user:me SQLite
```

Which found a bunch of things. I dug through the results and saw this snippet for [one of my answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15671600/add-lots-of-data-to-sqlite-database-in-c-sharp/15671802#15671802):

> From my experience, wrapping as many database calls as possible into a transaction speeds things up quite a bit: using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath)) { db.RunInTransaction(() => { …

Notice that the snippet contains both "SQLite" and "RunInTransaction". In looking at the post itself I noticed "SQLite" was in the question title and in my answer as code. I also noticed that "RunInTransaction" is only in my answer in code.

I looked at meta and saw [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55473/search-just-code), which says I need to prefix any code with `code:`, so I tried:

```
user:me SQLite code:RunInTransaction
user:me code:SQLite code:RunInTransaction
```

None of the above returned any results.

I also found [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange) on meta which says I can search for code like this (without the `code:` prefix):

> ["COUNT(*) AS UpVotes"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22COUNT%28%2a%29+AS+UpVotes%22)

So I tried:

```
SQLite RunInTransaction
"SQLite RunInTransaction"
```

The first did not return my answer. The second did not return any results.

**So my question:**

How do I properly search for [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15671600/add-lots-of-data-to-sqlite-database-in-c-sharp/15671802#15671802), that has both "SQLite" and "RunInTransaction" in the post?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whole words only, that's the problem here. Not sure if it's a bug or by design.

For what it's worth, [this query](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1822514+SQLite+db.RunInTransaction) will return what you're after:

```
user:1822514 SQLite db.RunInTransaction
```

Comment: that's likely done for performance reasons.  "contains" string comparisons can't be used in a search index very effectively.

Comment: At least that's better than "db.RunInTransaction(()" :) Seriously though I would think that "db.RunInTransaction" would be tokenized into two words.

Comment: @chuex Servy is probably right, as for two words, there's no space thus considered one word.

Comment: I don't like the tokenization rules regarding the period, but that seems to be the issue. Thank you for your time.