# Having trouble searching for "C gui" - "C" isn't included in the search

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

I'm trying to search for questions with "C" and "gui". Ideally, I would just see all questions tagged with both of these words. When I search "C", I get absolutely nothing. When I search for "C gui" or "gui C", I get the same results as I do when I search for "gui".

I can click on the "C" tag in my "Interesting Tags" section, but then I can't search those questions for GUI.

What am I doing wrong? It seems like a relatively simple search.

**Edit:**

So, using advice from some of the people that have answered, I can successfully find what I need using the search `[c] [gui]`.

That works, **but**... why doesn't the search `C gui` include "C" in the search?

Comment: This is a serious bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To search for tags on questions, wrap the tag in [].  So, your search would be [**[c] [gui]**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c+gui)

As for *c* not being converted to *[c]* I will surmise a guess that there's a 3 character limit on a term being used.  3 character limits are common throughout other parts of S[OFUE] so it seems logical this is used here.

<sub>At least in my head it seems logical!</sub>

---

**EDIT:**
StackOverflow doesn't include stop words in its search for optimization purposes ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24575/so-sites-dont-search-for-common-words/24578#24578)).  Here's a list of [stop words](http://www.link-assistant.com/seo-stop-words.html).  Notice *c* is on the list.  Anybody want to bet that the step eliminating stop words happens before the tag check?

Comment: I guess that would make sense, but I have nothing to add when I want to search for questions in C... I guess you have to use `mykeyword [c]`

Comment: assuming your list is comprehensive, it seems that [c] is the *only* tag that this applies to, since it's the only top-50 tag which is a stop word. Nevertheless, it *is* a problem. Perhaps the bug is that C is considered a stop word at all on a programmer's site.. but more generally for SE, the bug is probably that stop words are killed before popular tags are checked.

Comment: Right.  I did look on SO to see if there was another tag we could use to test.  Perhaps on one of the other sites in the network but I didn't look.  By no means do I know for certain this is the answer, just attempting to piece together the puzzle.

Comment: I found that "make", being a stopword (but also the name of a handy build tool and hence a tag name) is also not auto-translated to a tag search.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a tag with [square-brackets]. So, you could search for [c] [gui] as a workaround.

It seems distinctly odd that [gui] gets recognised as a tag automatically, but [c] doesn't, when [c] is a far bigger tag. Particularly when the search help says:

> Results are weighted heavily towards
>   question title matches, and any search
>   terms matching the most popular 50
>   tags will be automatically mapped to a
>   tag to help narrow your search.

so there's clearly something gone awry here.

Comment: That worked for me. I'm still confused why C isn't included in the search.

Answer (score 0):

The reason 'C' wasn't included in your search is because the letter 'C' is probably in 90% of all posts.  The search would return far too many results and wouldn't be helpful at all.

Comment: [c] is one of the top 50 tags.  Why wasn't it converted to a tag search?

Comment: That's not true if it only matches whole words. I'm not sure how it searches. Either way -- it's odd that it just gets removed without warning.

Comment: @rch, true.  That's odd.

Answer (score 0):

This has now need resolved, it's included in the search.  Note that c# and c++ variants appear as well by default just because of how symbols work across the board.  That being said, "c" gui will show *only* the matches you're after.