# Need abbreviation for 'intitle:1'

Tags: feature-request, search

Most of my searches are based on searching keywords in post titles. Therefore I type 'intitle:1' quite often.

I would like to use an abbreviation instead like a single letter 'i' and cut on the keystrokes I have to type every time I do a search.

Comment: If you down vote, please add a useful comment.

Comment: As for the downvotes: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15251/meta-faq-page-should-include-more-verbiage-about-downvotes/15255#15255

Comment: @Arjan: Just put the comment. Don't make me think.

Comment: -1 to the above comment if I could, for "don't make me think," a phrase which is rarely a good sign.

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly, but I now downvoted, as apparently downvotes and comments are somehow related.

Comment: @Arjan, what sort of relationship are you referring to?

Comment: @Popular Demand: Read the book "Don't make me think". While its for web usability, the principles apply to other facets of life. What good does it make if someone points me to a long list of possibilities? It's a lot more productive to type ' I don't like this idea because ...". Amazon doesn't allow ratings with no reviews. Same idea.

Comment: @Tony, the reason you just presented is exactly the reason that I said "rarely a good sign" rather than "never a good sign."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think that will happen, since StackOverflow must support one letter tags like `C`. When the `I` language is created, how are you going to support that?

---

Here's something you *can* do, however.

If you are using Chrome, right click on the address bar and pick *Edit Search Engines*. Click on *Add* and fill in as follows:

```
Name:    StackOverflow Title Search
Keyword: so
URL:     http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=intitle:1+%s
```

(Instructions are similar for Firefox.)

Now your intitle search can be done by writing, e.g., <kbd>so threading in python</kbd> in your address bar.

Comment: A superb idea, sir!

Comment: Actually, the search will strip singular letters. If you want to search the [C] tag, you need to surround it in brackets. [C alone won't cut it](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c), not even [if it is accompanied by other terms](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c+truffles).

Comment: Related to @Grace's examples:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62859/having-trouble-searching-for-c-gui-c-isnt-included-in-the-search

Comment: Good enough for me. It's a bookmarklet now.

Comment: Why would any of the operators conflict with tags, the colon defines them so that there is no conflict.

Answer (score 0):

I think all qualifiers should be able to be shortcutted to the minimum required to define the operator, so for **intitle:** we could use **int:**, for **inquestion:**, **inq:**, etc.