# Why doesn't searching for C questions work?

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, tag-search

When I search for questions tagged with the C programming language, I get [this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c). It only works if I search `[c]` instead. Searching directly works with other languages, like C++, C#, Java etc. What's the problem?

<sub>Since I have a hunch that it's probably just some stupidity of mine, I better not tag it as a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug).</sub>

Comment: It's probably because `c` is only one character.

Comment: Related: [Having trouble searching for "C gui" - "C" isn't included in the search](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/62859)

Comment: Luckily, the stackoverflow team implemented tags.

Comment: a bug ... we should fix it

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't search for single characters (try ["a"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=a), for example) — it just redirects you to the [search help page](/search).

It probably is a bug, still. Search terms that correspond to a top 40 tag are supposed to be treated as a tag automatically. My guess is the length check is performed before the tag conversion is done.

Answer (score 6):

Single character searches are now supported, there are some mathematical symbols and cases like `c` on Stack Overflow that make sense to support and we are technically able to now...so it's enabled.  Note that "a" is a stop word, so it's a bad test :)

Answer (score 5):

Think about it for a minute.

If I search for "a" I'm going to get nearly every post on SO. If I search for "c" same thing. Using [c] narrows the search to the c tag.

If I search for a++ I'm not getting anything as its not a common letter, but if I search for c++ I'll get any post with "c++" in the body.  (sure c++ redirects you to the tag search, but a single c is more likely to be a mishit enter key)

Searching for a single letter is useless, even if that letter means something in this context.

Comment: Searching for `'java'` will find all posts tagged `'java'`.  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java

Comment: @rocket see parenthetical

Comment: Ah, yes.  Silly me, you did mention that.

Comment: @Rocket I was probably adding it while you were typing :)