# Cannot search for 'like'

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, search

I'm not going to speculate on the cause of this bug (although my money's on it being a SQL keyword), but is it a known bug that searching for 'like' on StackOverflow sends the user to the same page that they would see if they hadn't entered any search terms at all (submitted the search form blank)?

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. On StackOverflow...
2. In search box, enter 'like'
3. Submit

I have tried it on StackOverflow and Meta.

Comment: That's by design. The search doesn't work for a whole lot of stop words, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24575/so-sites-dont-search-for-common-words/24578#24578).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Related reading:

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/11/stop-me-if-you-think-youve-seen-this-word-before.html

Workaround:

on https://stackoverflow.com/search try the Google option presented there.